# Whose view actually increases the view count in SO?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, views

Is this google, yahoo search, etc?

Answer (score 2):

View counts are calculated by unique visitors. This means, presumably, that each IP that views your question will count as a view.

Currently the views are bugged and they will be fixed soon. The bug was deployed earlier tonight, and will be fixed whenever they deploy again.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer here - you do!  View counts are now fixed - resume viewing and we have resumed counting.